# Efficient way to perform top10 records for each category

Tags: sql-server

I have the following table from machines that send parameters every 2 minutes, it has several equips and millons of rows (table has no indexes)

```
     Time         Equip Parameter
01/01/2021 12:00    A   103
01/01/2021 12:02    B   102
01/01/2021 12:00    A   101
01/01/2021 12:00    B   102
01/01/2021 12:04    C   103
```

I want to make sure machines are sending at least 5 parameters every day in order to monitor they are communicating, so i use a top5 record for each category strategy, this is my best query so far:

```
select Equip,Parameter,Time
from (
    select Parameter,Equip, Time,row_number() over (partition by Equip,Parameter order by Time desc) as country_rank 
    from Table a with (NOLOCK)
    where Time Between  DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0) AND DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE())-0, 0)) ranks
where country_rank <= 5
```

This query takes at least 6 min to perform, is it possible to upgrade this query so it takes less time? Im using 2008.

Regards

Comment: Management studio is not relevant, which version of sql server are you using? Why are you overiding SQL's locking strategy with NOLOCK? For any useful help you'll need to provide details of the table's schema, indexes and constraints.

Comment: Is there an index on `Time`?

Comment: i edited the question, hope it is clear enough now, sorry im not an sql expert, please let me know if there is something else missing

Comment: Stop splattering your code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: so that is the answer to my question? i just need to remove the no lock? thats gonna make my query faster?

Comment: `NOLOCK` not directly relevant, just that removing `NOLOCK` *may* make it slightly slower, but at least you will get correct results all the time. You are going to need indexing here. Very much depends on the cardinality (how many rows per `Equip,Parameter` group, how many are likely to match). If there are only a very small percentage likely to match then an index `Time INCLUDE (Equip,Parameter)` is likely best. If there are many groups and a large chunk of their rows match, then you probably want `Equip,Parameter,Time`. There are other tricks if necessary, need to see the execution plan

Answer (score 0):

Just to let you know, i've found a solution that takes less than a minute to perform:

```
select distinct round(convert(FLOAT,CONVERT(DATETIME, DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0)))+2,6) ReadTime, Equip,Parameter
from table
where Time Between DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0) AND DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE())-0, 0)
order by Time desc
```

regards